# Is it possible to reduce the block interval in the future?

Tags: block-interval

Is it possible in future to reduce the confirmation time of the transactions? Can it somehow be reduced to less than 10 minutes? Can it be made faster?

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/43700/how-does-the-lightning-network-work-in-simple-terms http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/44416/lightning-network-scaling-alternatives http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/46618/lightning-network-and-lightweight-clients

Comment: You could browse the [Bitcoin Improvement Proposals](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/README.mediawiki); that's the standard way to suggest innovations.

Answer (score -1):

Yes and no. Any change to the protocol is possible if and only if > 50% of the active nodes "agree" to it by adopting that protocol change.

Getting everyone to agree is very hard though. For example, [Bitcoin Cash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitcoin_Cash) (BHC) exists as a fork of Bitcoin because of a dispute over increasing the block size. It seems likely such a push to lower the block time would lead to a similar messy debate and ultimately a split.

Comment: That’s not true. Why would >50% of active nodes need to agree?

Comment: My understanding is that the difficulty level is adjusted every 2 weeks by consensus (I.e. > 50%). It’s adjusted up or down with the goal of keeping the block time at 10 minutes. So if only some nodes wanted to create blocks faster they would create blocks at a lower difficulty level, which would mean they would have a different notion of what a valid block hash is. Part of the network would see those hashes as valid and part would not. The majority rules. The others must fall in line or exist as a fork.

Comment: The difficulty is not set by consensus; it is protocol rule. If miners produce blocks that do not follow the protocol's difficulty rule, those blocks are invalid - period. You need a fork of the system to adjust this rule, meaning a separate currency if both the old and new rules remain popular to some.